# how to capture a specific data from the large string?

Tags: java, arrays, regex, string

I am extracting data from pdf and storing in string, from this large data i want to store some specific data in fields.

I have tried some code for one occurrence it is working but how to capture all the data that is needed?

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.pdfbox.io.IOUtils;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.text.PDFTextStripper;

public class LdcReaderDemoNew {
    private static final Pattern END_OF_SENTENCE = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s+");

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String filePath = "C:\\Users\\Admin\\Downloads\\Ldc.pdf";
        String text = convertPDFToTxt(filePath);
         //String[] word = {"CERTIFICATE UNDER SECTION","Certificate No","rate of"};

        String word = "Certificate No";
        String str = getSentence(text, word);
        String str1[] = str.split(":");
        String[] str2 = str1[1].split(" ");
        System.out.println(str2[1]);
    }

    public static String convertPDFToTxt(String filePath) throws IOException {
        byte[] thePDFFileBytes = readFileAsBytes(filePath);
        PDDocument pddDoc = PDDocument.load(thePDFFileBytes);
        PDFTextStripper reader = new PDFTextStripper();
        String pageText = reader.getText(pddDoc);
        pddDoc.close();
        return pageText;
    }

    private static byte[] readFileAsBytes(String filePath) throws IOException {
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
        return IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    }

    public static String getSentence(String text, String word) {
        final String lcword = word.toLowerCase();
        return END_OF_SENTENCE.splitAsStream(text).filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(lcword)).findAny().orElse(null);
    }

}
```

for e.g. "i have certificate no: 0218AU464E" i want to store 0218AU464E in one string. like wise i want to capture below data in separate fields.

1)195(2)

2)0218AU464E

3)MUMT17510D

4)SHELF DRILLING OFFSHORE SERVICES ' INDIA ) PRIVATE LIMITED Address 4TH FLOOR CHEMTEX

5)1218694350

6)4%

7)SHELF DRILLING C.E.THRONTON,LTD

8)AASCS2718N

9)01-APR -18

10)31-MAR-19

```
CERTIFICATE UNDER SECTION 195(2) OF THEINCOME TAX ACT, 1961 RELATING TO DEDUCTION OF 
TAX AT SOURCE 
Office of Assistant/Deputy  Commissioner ofIncome Tax 
INT TAX CIRCLE4(2)(1),M 

Certificate No : 0218AU464E Pnnt Date : 10-MAY-18 To, 
TAN  MUMT17510D 
Name SHELF DRILLING OFFSHORE SERVICES ' INDIA ) PRIVATE LIMITED Address 4TH FLOOR CHEMTEX 
HOUSE MAIN STREET POWAi MUMBAI 
MAHARASHTRA - 400076 


Ihereby authorl%e you to pay or credit Other sums upto Rs. 1218694350 after deducting income tax 
at the rate of 4 % (Excluding Education cess/surcharge as applicable) to or, as the case may be to the 
acoount of   SHELF DRILLING C.E.THRONTON,LTD.whose details are as below : 

PAN : AASCS2718N 
UnlUBranch : N A. 
Address : SHELF DRILLING C ETHRONTON LTD 4TH FLOOR CHEMTEX HOUSE MAIN STREET 
HIRANANDANIGARDENS POWAi MUMBAI 
MAHARASHTRA - 400076 

over whom I have jurisdiction forissue of this certificate. 

Th s certificate is non-transferable and valid for above PAN holder for payments or credit by 
whatever name called whichever is earlier from 01-APR -18 to 31-MAR-19, unless It Is cancelled by 
me under intimation to you before that date. 
The above certificate number should be quoted in the quarter y TDS statement for the relevant
```

Comment: will the pdf always have the same format? E.g will the pdf always start with 'CERTIFICATE UNDER SECTION "XXX" OF '..

Comment: yes it will start from 'CERTIFICATE UNDER SECTION'

Answer (score 1):

This can be done a very dirty way, using capture groups. Assuming the general layout of the text is going to be the same each time, and only THOSE values will change, you could use something along these lines:

```
/^.*?(?<=^CERTIFICATE UNDER SECTION )(\d+(?:\(\d+\))?).*?(?<=Certificate No : )([\dA-Z]+).*?(?<=TAN  )(MUMT[\dA-Z]+).*?(?<=Name )([^\n]+).*?(?<=Rs\. )(\d+).*?(?<=at the rate of )(\d+\s*%).*?(?<=of )\s*(.*?)\.whose details.*?(?<=PAN : )([A-Z\d]+).*?(?<= from )(.*?)(?= to ).*?(?<= to )(.*?),.*?$/s
```

This will extract a) the whole string as a match) and b) the values you indicated you wanted to extract as capture groups.

See this in action:

https://regex101.com/r/vODJyt/1

Obviously, whilst it works, as I say it's dirty, it's prone to fail if something changes, but you could update the regex to work around these, but for the string provided, this extracts all values you want at once.

**NOTE - You need to provide the `single line`, or `/s` switch to allow `.` to capture `\n` characters**

Comment: question : how did you manage to make this regex so fast?

Comment: @ThanosM it wasn't THAT fast... I just copy/pasted his string and went through adding negative look-behinds where they were needed lol

Comment: What is the difference bettween your regex and making something like this for the whole String "(CERTIFICATE UNDER SECTION) (.*) (OF THEINCOME TAX ACT)".This way you just need to capture specific groups after regex match.

Comment: Again, assuming it will be the same / similar... yeah `.*?` would work there too but I figured in case they were just going to be numbers, to enforce that. I've updated my answer to make the `\(\d\)` part optional.

Comment: This is safer yes

Answer (score 0):

Better, use Entity Extraction API. [named-entity-recognition](https://towardsdatascience.com/named-entity-recognition-with-nltk-and-spacy-8c4a7d88e7da)

Or you can do one thing, Make a template or format of pdf. You can parse it.